# Groovy enums - call chains

Tags: groovy, enums, chain

I am surprised to see that chaining calls to an enum works. I happened to have an enum instance called 'name' and that was referenced instead of the name() when I forgot the brackets. Should enum's allow chaining calls?
Using Groovy 2.4.10 - see the last 3 calls below:

```
Groovy Shell (2.4.10, JVM: 1.8.0_121)
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.

groovy:000> public enum Compass { north, south }
===> true
groovy:000> Compass.north
===> north
groovy:000> Compass.north.name
ERROR groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException:
No such property: name for class: Compass
groovy:000> Compass.north.name()
===> north
groovy:000> public enum Compass { north, south, name }
===> true
groovy:000> Compass.north.name()
===> north
groovy:000> Compass.north.name
===> name
groovy:000> Compass.north.south
===> south
groovy:000> Compass.north.south.north
===> north
```

Comment: FWIW, Java exhibits the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct. Enums, in Java, are a syntactic sugar (plus useful stuff like `values()` and `name()`) over static fields in that same class, thus, when you call an enum field, you have also a static reference to that class, which also has access to the other class' fields:

```
class Compass {
    static NORTH = new Compass()
    static SOUTH = new Compass()
}


assert Compass.NORTH.SOUTH.NORTH == Compass.NORTH

def west = new Compass()
assert west.SOUTH == Compass.SOUTH
```